# Python Pandas Merge Memory error

Tags: python, pandas, merge, out-of-memory

I am trying to merge n number of files on a column.
I am using pandas python 3.
i have csv files which have some common columns but if i try to merge on a column which has no common value among different files then i get this error

```
File "pandas\_libs\join.pyx", line 180, in pandas._libs.join.full_outer_join
ValueError: array is too big; `arr.size * arr.dtype.itemsize` is larger than 
the maximum possible size.
```

Data is too big, like each csv file has 15000 rows.

Code:

```
for i in range(nfiles):
 a.append(pd.read_csv(files[i],dtype='object',quotechar='"',encoding='UTF8',
            quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL,low_memory=True))

df=a[0]
for df_ in a[1:]:
        df = df.merge(df_, how='outer',on=asw)
        df.to_csv("output.csv", index=False)
```

please provide a possible solution.

Comment: Try using `dask` ...

Comment: Dask is a good way if caching to disk is actually necessary.  You say 15,000 rows, which isn't very big, but how many columns and how many files are there?  It may just actually be too big to do in memory.

Comment: 15 files some with 1500 rows and some with 20000 rows.
and columns are not fixed..some files have 8 columns and some have 15 columns and column names don't match among different files.'
There are null values in many columns.

Comment: Thank You @coldspeed and Jeff . Dask works for me.